# Yandex.ru settings in Google analytics are not being recognised

Tags: google-analytics, yandex

By default the Yandex.com traffic is recognised just fine in Google Analytics (universal version) but try as I might I cannot get the yandex.ru traffic to show up as organic. I get a lot of Yandex search clicks, way more than Google and want to see them in the organic category instead of "direct".
I can see the traffic in my access logs, here is an example incoming string:

```
http://yandex.ru/yandsearch?text=Urzd+Miejski+Szczecin&lr=213
```

My entry in the "organic search sources" is very simple indeed as per these settings, but doesn't seem to work. Everything still comes in as Direct. Thanks if anyone knows what I could try next.

```
Search Engine Name: Yandex-RU

Domain Name: yandex.ru

Query Parameter: text

Path:
```